# How to access @Args() in @ResolveField in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a query for getting projects from the DB which has args as shown below for filtering projects. How would I use the same args in the @resolveField for filtering form values of the project

```js
@Query(() => [Project])
async getProjects(@Args() projectArgs: ProjectArgs) {
  return await this.projectsService.find(projectArgs);
}

@ResolveField("formValues", () => [FormValues])
async getFormValues(@Parent() project: Project) {
  const { id } = project;
  return await this.formsService.findValues({ projectId: id});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem before and through thorough searching, I have come to the conclusion that the best and scalable way of doing this is to define the args for the field resolver itself. Here is how you do it

```
@ResolveField("formValues", () => [FormValues])
async getFormValues(@Args() projectArgs: ProjectArgs) {
  ..../////
}
```

This way you will have to pass the args just as you pass it in the parent query. Or you could leave them out if you don't want to filter the form values

There are other approaches that you can use. One of them is by setting the info as

```
@Query(() => [Project])
async getProjects(@Args() projectArgs: ProjectArgs, @Info() info) {
  info.variableValues.some_key = value
  return await this.projectsService.find(projectArgs);
}
```

But this won't scale and make it very tightly coupled

Comment: It's unfortunate that there isn't a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I was able to deal with that was to create own resolver interceptor `FooBarInterceptor`, get args from `Context` and add them into `Request` object (taken from `Context`).
Then I can create a params decorator to grab args from `Request` and return them.

Here's an example:

1. Interceptor

```js
// ./foo-bar.interceptor.ts

export class FooBarInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req } = ctx.getContext();

    // Write every query args to the request object
    req.args = ctx.getArgs();

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

2. Args decorator

```js
// ./query-args.decorator.ts

export const QueryArgs = createParamDecorator((data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext): any => {
  const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);

  const { req } = ctx.getContext();

  // Get the query args from the request object
  return req.args;
});
```

3. Actual resolver

```js
// ./foo-bar.resolver.ts

@UseInterceptors(FooBarInterceptor) // <-- Register interceptor for `Resolver`
@Resolver(() => FooBar)
export class FooBarResolver {
  // ... some queries ...

  @ResolveField()
  async customField(
    @QueryArgs() args: any, // <-- Use decorator for field resolver
    @Parent() fooBar: any,
  ) {
    console.log('ResolveField: Args', args, 'Parent', fooBar);

    return 'custom-value';
  }
}
```

I'm still not sure about how well it would scale, but at least look convenient enough to try :)